# How can I count the number of users in a custom uppercase user group on MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I need to count the number of users in a MediaWiki custom user group. According to https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Statistics I can use the following magic word to do so:

```
{{NUMBERINGROUP:Writer}}
```

However, I cannot get this to work with "Writer". I've written it with capitals and in lower case, and tried the plural form, Writers, to no avail.

In contrast, counting the number of users in the "Bureaucrats" group does work:

```
{{NUMBERINGROUP:Bureaucrat}}
```

On https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights there is an example creating the custom "ninja" user rights group. The example suggests creating the pages:

```
MediaWiki:Group-ninja (content: Ninjas)
MediaWiki:Group-ninja-member (content: ninja)
```

I looked at the equivalent groups for bureaucrats on my wiki and found:

```
MediaWiki:Group-bureaucrat (content: Bureaucrats)
MediaWiki:Group-bureaucrat-member (content: Bureaucrat)
```

As counting the number of users that are bureaucrats works, I decided to create:

```
MediaWiki:Group-writer (content: Writers)
MediaWiki:Group-writer-member (content: Writer)
```

When this didn't work, I changed the contents on the second page from "Writer" to "writer" (lower case), which had no effect.

Does anyone know what I can do to make this work? Preferably from within the wiki, without having to access any server files.

Comment: On your wiki, does one of Special:ListUsers/Writer or Special:ListUsers/writer or Special:ListUsers/Writers or Special:ListUsers/writers show you any users?

Comment: @MarkA.Hershberger Note: I had to edit my comment as what I had said was appearing all jumbled together. Please refer to this paste for my answer: http://pastebin.com/YuPHQE4t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your LocalSettings.php, you've specified "Writer" instead of "writer".  This is fine, but it will cause *some* confusion when you start dealing with changing labels and such.

For instance, after some testing, it looks like NUMBERINGROUP is changing "Writer" to "writer" and returning 0 because that group (the lower-case one) doesn't exist.  This is the only place I've found a problem and it deserves a [bug report](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/BUGREPORT).

Other ways this will confuse you:

Instead of using:

```
MediaWiki:Group-writer (content: Writers)
MediaWiki:Group-writer-member (content: Writer)
```

you'll need to use:

```
MediaWiki:Group-Writer (content: Writers)
MediaWiki:Group-Writer-member (content: Writer)
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I created the two latter groups, unfortunately NUMBERINGROUP is still returning 0. Does this mean I'd have to change the group name from "Writer" to "writer" in LocalSettings.php?

Comment: Changing it in LocalSettings.php may not work, but you can try.  If you file a bug report about this, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Will do. I completely forgot to mention that this is on MediaWiki 1.15.1 -- I'm going to test on 1.21.2 as well before filing the bug report.